# Is it necessary to use/make a script that make django development easier?

Tags: python, django

I just start a django-fairy project for django 1.3.1 here: https://github.com/goFrendiAsgard/django-fairy
It is just a simple (but I think useful) python script that can help django newbie to develop everything faster. The basic idea is:

1. When you make a view, usually you will make respective url and template
2. When you make a model, usually you will register it on admin

So that it would be more fun, if there is a way to do such a things in a simple way.
I want to make sure if what I do is right.

So these is my questions:

1. Do you think that such a project is useful for community?
2. Is it violate django (and python) philosophy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you think that such a project is useful for community?

Yes, just keep developing it plus, you will know that from the users as feedback and even if the feedback wasn't good enough, let your project be, enhance it more and more and your project will get a good rating and acceptance in no time. Just consider your users' notes and comments and you will be fine.

> Is it violate django (and python) philosophy?

No, it is not.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, Let me ask a bit more:

Is there any place such a "django-official-forum" or whatever where I can let the community know about this and waiting their feedback?

(I was make thing with CodeIgniter before, and there is a CodeIgniter forum to publish my work)

Comment: There are plenty on the web, here is a small list:
[Django User's Mailing List](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users)  - [Django Developers Mailing Lists](http://groups.google.com/group/django-developers) - [The Django Forum](http://thedjangoforum.com/) The latter is a small but a very helpful community.

Good luck in this project!

Answer (score 0):

1. The only way to tell if it is useful is for you to complete it and publish it and people start using it.
2. No, there are tons of other quick bootstrapping scripts available for django. There is no such policy that prevents this.

However, you shouldn't make a lot of assumptions as to what the end user will want to do with their models/views. Django is a toolset and as such there are lots of ways to use it.

For example, there are models that are never entered in the admin, and similarly there are django sites that don't have a "front end" (ie, a view) and only use the ORM and the admin, with applications like [databrowse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/databrowse/)

Comment: I'm fully aware with that. So that when I modify manage.py, I only add things, not change any functionality.

So whenever someone intend to do something in my assumption, he/she will run "python manage.py fairy", but if he/she just want to make a normal application, model, or view, he/she can still do it in conventional way.

BTW, can you please give some example of such a bootstrapping scripts? I think it would be good to have comparison, and ensure that I don't re-invent the wheel :)

thanks for your comment